# Sum of Gauss sum

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, arithmetic

Let $p$ be an odd prime, $v \in \mathbb{N}$ be a positive integer, and $c\in \mathbb{Z}$. Set
\begin{align}
G(c,p^v):=\sum_{\substack{d \bmod p^v \\  (d,p^v)=1}}{  \left(\frac{d}{p^v}\right) {e}^{ { \frac{2\pi i cd}{p^v} }}},&&\text{where }\left(\frac{\cdot}{p}\right) \text{ is the usual Legendre symbol}.
\end{align}

My question: What is 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{v}G(c,p^i) ~~?
$$

Best regards.

Comment: I've looked into a question very similar to this before, and I [wrote some of it down](http://davidlowryduda.com/?p=1181). My $H_m(c)$ is the Gauss sum, but my final results aren't on $\sum H_n(c)$ but instead $\sum H_n(c) c^{-s}$ as a Dirichlet series. Perhaps you'll find it helpful?